# Performance of Numbers 3.0 for large calculation sheet

Tags: numbers

When I used previous versions of Numbers to work with files containing a lot of large formulas, the performance of many actions were slow, including scrolling.  Can you comment how about the latest software update from Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just purchased and tried out Numbers 3.0, and Apple definitely improved the calculation process, as my sheets using large formulas already perform much faster. Performance is better.

Comment: You could mark your answer as accepted so that others can decide whether or not to look at this question.